# NodeJS unable to connect socket

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, raspbian

So I am new to Node.js and following some tutorials. I am trying to just do a basic socket connection with Https since the tutorial only used https.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/key.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/server.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// your express configuration here
var serv = https.createServer(credentials, app);

app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/client/index.html');
});
app.use ('/client',express.static(__dirname+'/client'));
serv.listen(8080);
console.log('server started');

var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('socket connection');
});
```

I never see socket connection on console.

here is the HTML

```
hello world
<script src="https://cnd.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong here? does Socket.io support https?

Comment: Can you paste what command you are using and what console prints to your command?

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~/app $ node test.js
server started

Comment: Okay try below code once. from the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, if you have express then you don't need https to create server.

Here's what you can do:

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('socket connection');
});
```

If you run this code, `socket connection` will be printed on console.

Comment: Http is not secure.

Comment: Then use https... The question here is **if it is working now**... Don't just get diverted and point out other things, if you are asking help! Is it working now?

Comment: I solved it, basically it was a combination of bad syntax and lack of ssl keys. I wouldn't be able to submit a good answer.

Comment: Was my answer any helpful to you?